# Confidence interval of a biased estimator that's asymptotiacally unbiased.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

Suppose I have an estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ of $\theta$ where $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_n] \neq \theta$, but I do know that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_n] = \theta$.

Also suppose that $\hat{\theta}_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$ and from the above we then have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n = \theta$.

Is there any way to construct confidence intervals of the form with probability $\geq 1 - \delta$, $\theta \in [\text{lower bound}, \text{upper bound}]$?

I was trying to find an upper bound on
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > \varepsilon) < \text{???}
$$
which we could then invert to get something of the form "with probability $\geq 1 - \delta$, $\theta \in [L(\hat{\theta}_n, n), U(\hat{\theta}_n, n)]$ where $L$ and $U$ are the lower and upper bounds.

Since for finite $n$, $\hat{\theta}_n$ isn't unbiased, we can't use standard Gaussian tail bounds or anything so I'm not sure what the best approach is here.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your stated distribution for $\hat{\theta}_n$ does not specify the relationship between the moments $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n^2$ and the true parameter $\theta$.  This means that there is presently insufficient information to form a pivotal quantity that would be the basis for a confidence interval.  If we make some assumptions about the relationship of these moments to the underlying parameter then we can form a pivotal quantity and derive an appropriate confidence interval formula.

For simplicity, I will assume that the variance $\sigma_n^2$ is unrelated to the underlying parameter, and that the mean is related to the underlying parameter through a monotonic function.  That is, you have $\mu_n = f_n(\theta)$ via some monotonically increasing function $f_n$ (we will denote the inverse function by $g_n = f_n^{-1}$).  Then you can write the pivotal quantity:

$$\frac{\hat{\theta}_n - f_n(\theta)}{\sigma_n} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

Taking $z_{\alpha/2}$ as the quantile of the standard normal distribution with upper tail area $\alpha/2$, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
1-\alpha 
&= \mathbb{P} \Big( z_{\alpha/2} \leqslant \frac{\hat{\theta}_n - f_n(\theta)}{\sigma_n} \leqslant z_{\alpha/2} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \Big( \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2} \leqslant \hat{\theta}_n - f_n(\theta) \leqslant \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \Big( \hat{\theta}_n - \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2} \leqslant f_n(\theta) \leqslant \hat{\theta}_n + \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \Big( g_n(\hat{\theta}_n - \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2}) \leqslant \theta \leqslant g_n(\hat{\theta}_n + \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2}) \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In the above equations we have taken $\hat{\theta}_n$ to be a random variable (i.e., prior to fixing the data).  Once the data is observed this statistic becomes a fixed value $\hat{\theta}_{n,\text{obs}}$ and we have the $1-\alpha$ level confidence interval:

$$\text{CI}_\theta(1-\alpha) = \Big[ g_n(\hat{\theta}_{n,\text{obs}} - \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2}), \text{ } g_n(\hat{\theta}_{n,\text{obs}} + \sigma_n \cdot z_{\alpha/2}) \Big].$$

(Note that this formula is for a monotonically increasing function $f_n$.  If the function were instead monotonically decreasing then the bounds of the confidence interval would be reversed.)

For simplicity, this particular confidence interval takes $\sigma_n$ as known.  If this is unknown then you would need to specify its relationship to the sample variance and you would probably then derive a similar interval, only using the critical values of the T-distribution instead of the normal distribution.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I guess I should have mentioned that  I'm trying to get a confidence interval that's independent of $\theta$. Recall that if we have $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we have that $\mathbb{P}(|\overline{X}_n - \mu| > \varepsilon) < 2e^{-n\varepsilon^2/2\sigma^2}$, and thus we can invert the above to have a $\geq 1 - \delta$ confidence inverval that doesn't depend on $\mu$.

So what I'm trying to do here is somehow using the consistency information about $\hat{\theta}_n$ to get something independent of $\theta$.

Comment: The same thing happens here - the above confidence interval is an interval *for* $\theta$ but it doesn't use $\theta$ in the formula (otherwise you couldn't calculate it from the observed data).  As you can see from the final formula for the confidence interval, it only uses $\hat{\theta}_n$ (which is a statistic).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I then have a followup question. Suppose the problem setting is exactly the same, but everything is now multivariate. Can we find confidence intervals in each dimension? Dude to the fact that now everything is multivariate, inverting $f_n$ will be infeasible since we now have projections at play.

Comment: If the extension is to the multivariate normal then you will still have univariate normal for the marginal distributions, so you could just apply the same method in a single dimension.  If you want a confidence interval for the vector parameter then you would form something analogous to the ellipses you get from a multivariate distribution, projected back with the inverse transformation.  Getting this would be non-trivial.

Comment: What is z_n in your formulae?

Comment: @Yaroslav: I've edited the answer to specify.